# Shabbos Zemiros source for Al Ahavosicha?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, provenance, shabbat-songs

My family sings a zemer called al ahavosich, which i have never seen in a standard bencher/zmiros book.

Does anyone know where this zemer comes from?

Comment: Could you please put up a recording of the nigun of this zemer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the song that you are referring to is [this one](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%9A), it was composed by [R' Yehuda HaLevi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_Halevi) in the 11th or 12th century according to Hebrew Wikipedia.

Comment: Great find. I had never heard of this one. Now that I read it's text it is indeed very beautifully written.

Comment: Someone can indicate the nigun corresponding to the text. (I am interested to singing this beautyful zemer )